# Image with hover effect comes above header when

Tags: html, css, image, header, hover

I have a fixed header, and it works perfectly: when scrolling, the images I have below disappear if the header is above. 
Then, I applied a hover effect to those images, setting opacity to them. Did not work. Whenever the header is above those images, and you put the mouse over, the part of the images that were below the header comes over it.

The CSS code utilized:

```
.imghover:hover {opacity: 0.4;}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps show the relevant code? We cannot see the issue from what you posted.

Comment: We will need related HTML and CSS code in order to help you out with this. Would be even better if could create a jsfiddle or something that reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try the " z-index " mostly there is problem in it of you need to add " z-index " to the image hover .